# What permissions needed to unlock items for a non-admin

Tags: powershell, role-management

We have a multi-lingual multisite instance with v10.1.3
And there are authoring roles for each site & role.

A common occurrence is, items are locked by a person who is unavailable and the current author does not have the option to unlock/check-in.  So, an admin would unlock those items.

For some items, the admin can see the `Elevated unlock` option and for some, that option is not available. So admin has to do a `Review > Check-in`.

1. Is there a way to unlock items that are locked by a specific user, using powershell.
2. Is there any way to give the option to the author itself, without making them an admin, like adding any default or custom role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Solution for unlocking items locked by a specific user.

```
Get-ChildItem master:\content -rec -Language * | 
  Where-Object { $_.Locking.GetOwner() -eq "sitecore\USERNAME" } | 
  % { $_.Locking.Unlock() }
```

2. Unlock Item command button in Sitecore Content Editor. Allow access of this button to specific role only.

```
public class UnlockItem : Command
    {
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
            if (context.Items.Length != 1)
                return;

            var item = context.Items[0];
            if (item.Locking.IsLocked() && item.Access.CanWrite())
            {
                using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
                {
                    item.Locking.Unlock();
                }
            }
        }

        public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
        {
            if (context.Items.Length != 1)
                return CommandState.Hidden;

            var item = context.Items[0];

            if (!item.Locking.IsLocked() || !item.Access.CanWrite())
                return CommandState.Hidden;

            return base.QueryState(context);
        }
    }
```

Patch config

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="contenteditor:unlockitem" type="MyAssembly.Namespace.UnlockItem, MyAssembly" />
    </commands>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And add a new button in core database under: `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Locks item`

Credit: https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-unlock-item-command

Hope it helps!

Comment: For #2 is there a just CMS approach, like adding a role?

Comment: No, you need to do some level of custom development.